# Is there a way to read a general ledger file into a Dataframe in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have two excel files which are in general ledger format, I am trying to open them as dataframes so I can do some analysis, specifically look for duplicates. I tried opening them using

`pd.read_excel(r"Excelfile.xls)`in pandas. The files are being read but when I use `df.head()` , I am getting nans for all the records and columns as well. Is there a way to load the data in general ledger format into a data frame?

[This is how the dataset looks like in the Jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LECfu.png)
[This is what the dataset looks like in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJrba.png)

I am new to stack overflow and I haven't learnt its full functionality to upload part of a dataset yet
I hope the images help in describing my situation

Comment: Hello.  Please provide some sample data and a minimal program that can be evaluated.  A "general ledger" file is a bit too broad of a description of the type of data in your spreadsheet.  One needs to be able to view the columns (e.g. account code, debit amount, credit amount, posting description, and so forth).  Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.